# How to handle lighting in orthographic projection in modern opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, lighting, orthographic

I had been doing lighting calculation in fragment shader in eye space coordinate for perspective projections ( both vertex shaders and fragment shaders are attached) and it had been working out fine.

But when the same shaders are used with orthographic projection or(FOV) Field of view is reduced in perspective projection (10-degree FOV) then it does not work well. Shading becomes weird.

[image: Weird shading image]

So far my understanding is that calculation of eye coordinate derivative becomes pointless in the fragemt shader because of the way orthographic projections works and the derivative of eye coordinate position is always zero except on edges ( correct me if I am wrong here as I have limited experience of working with computer graphics and OpenGL).
I am nor able to figure out How to do it correctly. It would be great if someone could point me to correct source of information.

Vertex Shader

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertex_position;

uniform mat4 transform_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_matrix;
uniform mat4 model_matrix;
out vec3 ec_pos;
void main()
{
 gl_Position = (view_matrix*transform_matrix*model_matrix*vec4(vertex_position, 1.0));
    ec_pos = gl_Position.xyz;
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;
uniform vec3 objectColor;
in vec3 ec_pos;
void main()
{
    vec3 lightColor = vec3(0.99,0.96,0.89);
    vec3 lightPos = vec3(0,0,0,1);
    vec3 ec_normal = normalize(cross(dFdx(ec_pos), dFdy(ec_pos)));
    float diff = max(dot(ec_normal, lightPos), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse =  diff * lightColor;
    vec3 result =  diffuse  * objectColor;
    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: *"Shading becomes weird"* - what is wired?

Comment: "*calculation of eye coordinate derivative becomes pointless in the fragemt shader*" But `ec_pos`, despite your naming convention, is not the eye-space position. It's the *clip-space position*.

Comment: I have just now solved my own problem by moving all the calculation in the world coordinate space.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I am new to this, I am sorry for incorrect terminology. I will edit the question with the correct term.

Comment: @Rabbid76, If you see the image the lighting was not taking the surface normals into consideration. Diffuse lighting component was almost the same all over the surface giving unexpected shading.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my own problem by doing the calculation in the camera coordinate space ( i.e, just before applying projection transformation). Here is the correct code:

Vertex Shader:

```
void main()
{
    vec4 mcPos = model_matrix*vec4(vertex_position, 1.0);
    vec4 wcPos = transform_matrix*vec4(mcPos);
    gl_Position = view_matrix*wcPos;
    mc_pos = mcPos.xyz;
    wc_pos = wcPos.xyz;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;
uniform vec3 objectColor;
in vec3 mc_pos;
in vec3 wc_pos;
void main()
{
    vec3 lightColor = vec3(0.99,0.96,0.89);
    vec3 lightPos = vec3(0,0,1);
    vec3 wc_normal = normalize(cross(dFdx(wc_pos), dFdy(wc_pos)));
    float diff = max(dot(wc_normal, lightPos), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = (diff) * lightColor;
    vec3 result = ( diffuse ) * objectColor;
    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
```

Correct shading

[image]